# SSH connection on a redhat server

Tags: ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, openssh, sshd, public-key

I have been struggling for the past few days trying to get an ssh connection working with a public rsa key on a redhat ftp server. I have been following guides such as this one with little luck:https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9194

I am currently able to connect with ssh and use the account that I have created. But I can't get the server to use only the public key and not prompt for a password.

If I do something like change the sshd_config file to not allow PAM, then it simply rejects me.

Here is some log output I get, with some info scrubbed for security and anonymity purposes.
https://pastebin.com/MzxhANHR

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Also quick note, I have made sure that the key generated has no password when generated (it is generated by a third party who wishes to connect to this server)

EDIT:
As I have been asked what I did to setup the key on the server. I had copied the keys into the authorized_keys file using the ssh-copy-id like so:

sudo ssh-copy-id -i /home/test/id_rsa.pub sftp@ftp.testserver.ca

I have made sure the authorized_keys file has the id_rsa.pub in it and that its chmod to 0600.

Comment: What does a directory listing of c:\users\test\.ssh show?

Comment: According to the debug output, the client offered *id_rsa* to the server and the server didn't accept it. What key were you expecting to work during the test? Please [edit] your question to describe in detail what you did on the server to set up the key that it's supposed to accept.

Comment: I have updated my question. but will comment here as well.
I have used: sudo ssh-copy-id -i /home/test/id_rsa.pub sftp@ftp.testserver.ca to specify the key.